# Capture "Done" button click in Apple virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have problem with my Comment component. He works correctly. but if use Iphone's "Done" button to edit comment text, keyboard close and any change is removed.
How can I capture this event? I use React with Material-UI.

It's Comment code

```
    <Box mt={1}>
      {!edit && !loading ? (
        <Typography
          variant="body2"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: prepareText(text)
          }} />
      ) : (
        <AnswerForm
          innerRef={formRef}
          disabled={loading}
          autofocus
          hideSubmit
          onComplete={handleComplete}
          onCancel={handleCancel}
          questionId={questionId}
          answerId={id}
          model={{ text }}
          onLoading={handleLoading}
        />
      )}
    </Box>
```

AnswerForm component code

```
<AppForm
  onValidSubmit={handleSubmit}
  model={model}
  className={className}
  validationErrors={validationErrors}
  formsyRef={innerRef}>
  <TextField
    required
    className={classes.textField}
    disabled={disabled || loading}
    ref={textfieldRef}
    inputRef={inputRef}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
    validations="isValidAnswer"
    name="text"
    label={!isMobile && 'Текст ответа'}
    placeholder={isMobile && 'Комментарий'}
    title="Для добавления ссылки используйте конструкцию [<имя_ссылки>|<ссылка>]"
    helperText={
      !isMobile && 'Для добавления ссылки используйте конструкцию [<имя_ссылки>|<ссылка>]'
    }
    InputProps={{
      disableUnderline: isMobile,
      endAdornment: (
        <InputAdornment>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="Добавить ссылку"
            title="Для добавления ссылки используйте конструкцию [<имя_ссылки>|<ссылка>]"
            onClick={handleClickRel}
            onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
            <RelLink />
          </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>
      )
    }}
    multiline
  />
  {!hideSubmit &&
    (loading ? (
      <Loading size="32px" center className={classes.loading} />
    ) : (
      <Button className={classes.button} color="secondary" type="submit">
        Ответить
      </Button>
    ))}
</AppForm>
```

[Comment component with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFCBK.png)

[Comment component in edit state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFazY.png)

Comment: Are you able to share a short snippet of code that demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: Sure, i shared code

Comment: Why don't you use `onChange` to capture the input?